# How to find my forgotten Firefox master password

Tags: passwords, master

I don't remember my Firefox master password. I changed it several days ago and now I'm  restricted on several functions.

Answer (score 1):

#### I don't remember my Firefox master password

There are two options:

1. Use [FireMaster](http://securityxploded.com/firemaster.php) to recover your password, or
2. Reset your Master Password.

See below for instructions.

---

#### Option 1: Use [FireMaster](http://securityxploded.com/firemaster.php) to recover your password

**About FireMaster**

> FireMaster is the First ever tool to recover the lost Master Password
>   of Firefox.
>
> Master password is used by Firefox to protect the stored
>   login/password information for all visited websites. If the master
>   password is forgotten, then there is no way to recover the master
>   password and user will lose all the passwords stored in it.
>
> However you can now use FireMaster to recover the forgotten master
>   password and get back all the stored Login/Passwords.
>
> FireMaster supports Dictionary, Hybrid, Brute-force and advanced
>   Pattern based Brute-force password cracking techniques to recover from
>   simple to complex password. Advanced pattern based password recovery
>   mechanism reduces cracking time significantly especially when the
>   password is complex.
>
> FireMaster is successfully tested with all versions of Firefox
>   starting from 1.0 to latest version v47.0

...

> License  : Freeware Platform : Windows XP, 2003, Vista, Windows 7,
>   Windows 8, Windows 10

Source [FireMaster - The Firefox Master Password Recovery Tool](http://securityxploded.com/firemaster.php)

See the source link for complete instructions

---

#### Option 2: Reset your Master Password

> Using the Master Password feature, you can protect all of your locally
>   stored usernames and passwords with a master password. If you have
>   forgotten your master password, you must reset it.
>
> Warning: Resetting your master password will remove all of your saved
>   usernames and passwords.
>
> 1. In the Firefox location bar, enter the following location:
>
>    ```
>    chrome://pippki/content/resetpassword.xul
>    ```
> 2. Press Enter.
> 3. The "Reset Master Password" page will appear. Click the Reset button, to reset your master password.
>
>    [image]

Source [Reset your Master Password if you've forgotten it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-your-master-password-if-you-forgot-it)